# insert multiple row to database from add row php form

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi I'm make form for add row in my php and want to insert for the database.
But I don't know how to passing that multiple row from my php page into my database
could you explain me and give me the solution for my problem?
maybe I'll show my code for understand

form php :

```
<div class="box box-primary">
  <div class="box-header">
    <h3 class="box-title">Detail Modules</h3>   
    <input class="btn btn-danger btn-flat pull-right" type="button" value="Delete Modules" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
    <input class="btn btn-info btn-flat pull-right" type="button" value="Add Modules" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />
  </div>
  <div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <table id="dataTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td width=10 align=center><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" class="minimal"/></td>
            <td>
              <label for="jenis_modules">Modules</label>
              <select name="jenis_modules[]" type="text" id="jenis_modules" class="form-control">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Modules</option>
                <option value="GL">General Ledger</option>
                <option value="AR">Account Receivable</option>
                <option value="AP">Account Payable</option>
                <option value="FA">Fixed Assets</option>
                <option value="CM">Cash Management</option>
                <option value="P">Purchasing</option>
                <option value="I">Inventory</option>
                <option value="OM">Order Management</option>
                <option value="FS">Fields Services</option>
                <option value="In">Integrasi</option>
              </select>
            <?php echo form_error('jenis_modules'); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <label for="descrip">Description</label>
              <input id="desc" class="form-control" type="text" name="desc[]" maxlength="200"/>
            <?php echo form_error('desc'); ?>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my process :

```
$modules = $this->input->post('jenis_modules');
$description = $this->input->post('desc');  
$save = mysql_query("INSERT INTO master_projects_line 
                         (project_id, modules, description)
                       VALUES
                         ('$project_id', '$modules', '$description')");
```

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: This is unclear. What is `addRow()` ?

Comment: what value you want multipal insert in database

Comment: You're a sitting duck for SQL Injection attack, the data isn't eveen escaped! User submitted data must **ALWAYS** be validated, no matter how well you trust the user. The mysql_* extension that you've used was **removed** from PHP version 7, you should now be using either the mysqli_* extension or PDO (and with whichever of them 2 you go for, you should **always** use prepared statements

Comment: [***DO NOT USE THE*** `mysql_*` ***API!***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: the value what I want to insert is jenis_modules and desc @Aslam Pater

Comment: @SpacePhoenix sorry because I'm new in PHP and I want to learn and know for my solution thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to convert `array` in to `string` and use `MYSQLI` `MYSQL` is depreciated.

You have only one description textarea so change name of textarea `desc[]` to `desc` if you still want to use as `desc[]` then use `$description[0]` in insert query.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$modules = implode(',',$this->input->post('jenis_modules'));
$description = $this->input->post('desc');  
$save = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO master_projects_line 
                     (project_id, modules, description)
                   VALUES
                     ('$project_id', '$modules', '$description')");
```

Comment: It's deprecated. This may or may not affect its resale value

Comment: @Vinie it just insert for the last row and for the desc is insert 'Array'

Answer (score 0):

Hope It helps.

```
$chk=$this->input->post('chk');
$modules = $this->input->post('jenis_modules');
$description = $this->input->post('desc');  
foreach($chk as $key=>$val){
     $modules=$modules[$key];  
     $description=$description[$key];
     $save = mysql_query("INSERT INTO master_projects_line 
                         (project_id, modules, description)
                         VALUES
                         ('$project_id', '$modules', '$description')");
}
```

Comment: @Jeffy Dwitra: u want to insert multiple row then use this code